# Find an object in Swift Array which has the same object multiple times in it

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I'm looking for an alternative to [`- [NSArray indexOfObject:inRange:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1415248-indexofobject) for Swift' `Array`s. What I'm trying to do is essentially following:

```
NSArray *A = @[@1, @3, @5, @4, @3];
NSUInteger cursor = 0;
while (YES) {
    NSUInteger res = [A indexOfObject:@3 inRange:NSMakeRange(cursor, A.count - cursor)];
    if (res == NSNotFound) {
        break;
    }
    NSLog(@"found 3 at %@", @(res));
    cursor = res + 1;
}
```

But I can't seem to find a way to start searching from a certain index with Swift Array. Of course I can make subarray, but is there better way to do this in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array slicing is the natural way to go about this:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
let range = 4...6
let desiredNumber = 2
let indexOfDesiredNumberInRange = numbers[range].index(of: desiredNumber)

print(indexOfDesiredNumberInRange as Any) // => Optional(4)
```

An since `ArraySlice` is just a view into the same backing storage of the soruce `Array`, there's no wasteful copying being done

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Yeah this is what I was looking for. Didn't realize ArraySlice is just a view of original Array :)

Comment: @taichino It is, up until a mutation is done either in the Array or the ArraySlice. At that point, a copy is made the preserve the immutability of other aliases: https://repl.it/repls/WhitesmokeDismalFlash

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to get all the indexes of the object you are looking for. This is a nicer way to do it

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,3,5,6,7,8]

for (num, index) in test.enumerated() {
    if num == 3 {
        print("found 3 at \(index)")
    }
}
```

Another way of giving you the indexes:

```
arr.enumerated().filter { (_, num) -> Bool in
    num == 3
}.map { $0.offset }
```

Comment: That's not what [`- [NSArray indexOfObject:inRange:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1415248-indexofobject) does

Comment: @Alexander It is what his total piece of code is doing

Comment: Thanks @Simon for your quick reply! I was about to do what you said but wondering if there is a better way. and I'm sorry my code in the question was confusing too...